# Selenium target has random numbers

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to test a web application that generates html id's with a random value in the middle. For instance: attribute_new_12493044135_name
The attribute defines the class of object that I want to find and the "name" is the unique part of this string. The problem is that I don't have Xpath 2.0 and thus can't use ends-with on the script. 
Can anyone help? I've tried to use Selenium Webdriver and IDE, and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Can you test for the start (i.e `attribute_new`) and then filter down the elements actually in code (i.e in C# or Java). It would be slow, but it's an alternative. If not, then I would hesitate to say this, but this application isn't really testable. Can you get your dev's to change it so that it has a better ID? Do the numbers relate to anything? I.e are they related to a specific ID in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed correct you can not use the ends-with function if you do not have access to the Xpath 2.0 library. But you do have access to all the Xpath 1.0 functions. http://www.edankert.com/xpathfunctions.html

You have two functions you can use to xpath to your element.

contains(): `//*[contains(@id, 'name')]`

substring(): `//*[substring(@id, string-length(@id)-3)="name"]`
The 3 in string-length is the number of  characters of your locator minus 1. ie 'name' has 4 characters so 4 - 1 = 3

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Also using a combination of css locators instead of the XPath will work:

```
[id*=attribute_new_][id*=_name]
```

OR:

```
[id^=attribute_new_][id$=_name]
```

Here's what the signs mean:

> "**^**" - prefixes / starts with
>
> "**$**" - suffixes / ends with
>
> "*" - substrings / contains

Comment: Selenium cannot use a combination CSS and XPath in one selector, if that is what you mean?

Comment: Not really, what I added above is just css selectors usage, no XPath there.

Comment: It could be used as is in those examples or combined farther with additional selectors, for e.g.:
`div[id*=attribute_new_][id*=_name]`
OR
`.something[id*=attribute_new_][id*=_name]`

Comment: I never said it could use a combination of Selectors & XPaths, I said you could use Selectors instead of XPath as in the examples given.